# IOS - Adding Image to UIImageView Causes Issues with Image Mode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

Recently I have observed some strange behaviour with the UIImageView and am wondering if anyone can provide some insite.  I have two UIImageViews with the images inside them being loaded from a database.  Inside the Xcode inspector I set the clip subview property and change the image mode to aspect fill.  This works fine, when the images are loaded they appear correctly in their views and are clipped as they should be.  However, I wanted to add a place holder image incase the user hadn't uploaded one yet.  When I did this it the image was not resized and and stretched passed its view.  I tried to reset the properties programatically as can be seen below, but nothing changed.

```
//code used to try to reset the image mode and clipping of the sub-views
//set up user profile picture
_profilePic.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
_profilePic.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_profilePic.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
_profilePic.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;

//set up users cover photo
_coverPhoto.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
_coverPhoto.clipsToBounds = YES;
_coverPhoto.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Why is this happening when I add an image to the view through the Xcode inspector but not when the image is left empty?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add them with the following line of code at the beginning of ViewDidLoad I get the same effect and have none of the unwanted image overflow.

```
_coverPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stockCoverPhoto.png"];
_profilePic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stockProfilePhoto.png"];
```

Not the most informative solution, as it provides no insight into this issue but it is a solution.  Anyone have any other input on how to fix this issue, why it even happens I would love to hear it as im still scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` instead of `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

Comment: No that didn't seem to help.  It's almost as if the act of manually putting an image into the UIImageView causes the properties of the view to be changed and changing them programmatically has no effect. @murat

Answer (score 0):

Same on here.. No way to change contentMode after setImage to UIImageView..